# How to change the name of the excel toolbar for all grids?

Tags: html, kendo-ui, localization, kendo-grid

How to change the name of the excel toolbar for all grids?
I try this, but it doesn't work!

```
kendo.ui.Grid.prototype.options.messages =
$.extend(true, kendo.ui.Grid.prototype.options.messages, {
  name: "excel page example."
});
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the code for your grid to your post?

Comment: I would like to do it through the rules of language

Comment: I wrote the code about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      toolbar: [{name:'excel',text:'custom excel export button'}],
      excel: {
          allPages: true
      },
      .
      .
      .

  });
```

Comment: If I wanted to do this with a rule in the message library, what should I do?

Comment: for all pages of the application